# Chrome Inspector Hover Issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, inspector

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue using the Chrome inspector:

If you inspect .outer and set the inspector to hover and then try to look at the styles of .inner whilst .outer is still hovered, the hover moves to .inner.

This is for this example CodePen:

http://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/xCfdB

Answer (score 2):

If you collapse the "Styles" section of the Chrome inspector before clicking .inner, this won't happen.

Comment: OMG! You are a lifesaver! This has been annoying me for ages!!  Thankyou so much! Why didn't I think of doing that!!

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer so that others who have this problem can easily find the solution :) Glad to have helped!

Comment: Hmm, Just tried it properly now and it sort of works but not quite. EG: If I choose hover on 1 element, collapse the styles bar and click a sub element, as soon as I reopen the styles panel to see the styles for that, then that elements takes on the hover. I need to see the styles for the sub element when the parent element is the one with the hover attached. This is what I need to know. Thanks for the help you gave anyway.